# substr and mb_substr return nothing

Tags: php, substr

I do not know what is wrong in the code below:

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('https://www.ibar.az/en/');
    $doc = new domDocument();

    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $ExchangePart = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');

    /*for ($i=0; $i<=$ExchangePart->length; $i++) {
        echo $i . $ExchangePart->Item($i)->nodeValue . "<br>";
    }*/

    $C=$ExchangePart->Item(91)->nodeValue;
    var_dump ($C);
    $fff=mb_substr($C, 6, 2, 'UTF-8');
    echo $fff;
    ?>
```

I have tried both substr and mb_substr but in both cases echo $fff; returns nothing.

Could anybody suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the var dump of $C output?

Comment: @Devon, $C outputs exactly what on the web page: string(218) " USD 1.5072 1.462 1.5494   "

Comment: I have used for loop to get the number of node (91) where the information  i am interested is located.

Comment: What does a `var_dump($fff);` output?  Based on that string, I would expect: `string(2) ".5"`

Comment: @Devon, it returns nothing...

Comment: @Devon, the output of the code is below: string(218) " USD 1.5072 1.462 1.5494   "

Comment: @Devon, the string in variable $fff containes whitespaces, so that's why i didn't get the data back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the item 91 node:

```
<ul>
    <li>USD</li>
    <li>1.5072</li>
    <li>1.462</li>
    <li>1.5494</li>
    <li class="down"> </li>
</ul>
```

This is node value:

```
¶
····························USD¶
································1.5072¶
································1.462¶
································1.5494¶
································•¶
····························

( · = space; • = nbsp )
```

`substr( $C, 6, 2 )` is a string of two spaces.

To correct retrieve all values:

```
foreach( $ExchangePart->Item(91) as $node )
{
    if( trim($node->nodeValue) ) echo $node->nodeValue . '<br>';
}
```

Otherwise, you can replace all node value spaces:

```
$C = str_replace( ' ', '', $C );
```

Comment: I think I will have to remove all spaces in order to make substr to work. Thank you.

Comment: could you please suggest how did you determined number of spaces and nbsp's? Grasias :)

Comment: I suggest you `foreach` method (It is more simple, sure and correct). I have simply used `str_replace` to replace spaces with a printable character. To count spaces you can use [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php), but it counts ALL blank spaces, regardless of their location. To remove spaces you can use `str_replace( ' ', '', $originalstring )`